# Figure out what's playing from a different device

Tags: macos, mac, itunes, osx-lion, airplay

I've been wondering if it's possible to figure out what video / song is currently playing
through airplay from a DIFFERENT device than the one that's streaming using airplay.

Surely this must be possible? i can't believe Apple didn't thought about the scenario where people want to know what's being played without constantly having to ask it :)

Thanks!

BTW: All computers in the network are macs, some use itunes, some use the airplay app.